# SQL Server 2012 SP1 to SP3 with Mirror

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Production server and DR server where the databases are mirrored, both on SQL Server 2012 SP1. I want to apply SP3. I can do this on a weekend and I don't want a failover.

Should these be the steps:

1. Pause data flow from Production to DR.
2. Apply SP3 to the DR server.
3. Apply SP3 to the Prod server.
4. Restart the dataflow

Comment: Please read the [MS support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/926824) for the same

Comment: Thanks for the link, I did see that. The link talks about failing over, I specifically don't want (or need to ) fail over. Will the mirror continue to function if I upgrade the DR machine first, then upgrade the Prod machine?

Comment: @dcorreia Please merge your accounts `dcorreia` and `david`

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you don't want to failover?

That would be the most common way. To do a rolling update and away you go.

If you have a witness, disable it first.

When you patch a mirror in this way the mirror will continue to function, to a fashion, and you'll have no application downtime.

When a mirror partner is patched it will leave the mirroring session, but then rejoin it when it is complete - then re-sync.

You can do it the way you described but you're going to have downtime when you patch the prod server and I'm guessing the patch when applied to Prod will trigger failover if that's how your mirror is configured.